# How to make Discord.py respond to a single message event twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a discord bot that can read all messages in a channel and add each message to a line in a .txt file, then respond confirming it did. I then want to have the bot wait 10 seconds then delete the original message and the response. I have code that can make this work. I had both working together as intended on my test bot. But when I copied the code to my main bot it wouldn't work and no longer would my test bot. The code I am posting is the test bot, right now it only deletes the original message as intended. If you leave out the second `@bot.event` chunk it responds and records the message as intended. How can I make both of these occur from the same bot? (The request channel bit is is from a failed attempt to have the code specify what channel the bot operates in rather than just close off each channel individually in discord). Both bots are in separate channels so I don't believe it is the bots actions interfering with eachother?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

requestsChannelID = 'CHANNELID'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    with open('requests.txt', 'a') as f:
        print(repr(message.content), file=f)
    await message.channel.send('Got it!')
    
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    if str(message.channel) == "requests" and message.content != "":
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: I think you have to combine your logic for `on_message` into one function because right now it looks like you have 2 identically-name functions.

Comment: I've had that thought. How would I incorporate that into the existing ```if```` statement. Because I want the bot to ignore itself in terms of responding and logging but include itself in the deletion. And the deletion needs to occur after the if statement. This  confusion is why its separated out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One thing I see is you should have `await bot.process_commands(message)`  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: You can limit the bot from responding to itself by checking IDs.  *Note that Bot does not have this problem*   
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message  This suggests that you do not have to check for `bot.user`.

Comment: In the second `on_message` event, you're checking if the content if the message is not empty, that doesn't make any sense, discord doesn't allow you to send empty messages

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`discord.Message.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete) to specifically delete both the request and the reply, no need to use purge (which quickly gets very complex when there are multiple messages within the 10s time frame)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    # ignore all channels but the specified one
    if message.channel.id == requestsChannelID:
        # record request
        with open('requests.txt', 'a') as f:
            print(repr(message.content), file=f)
        reply = await message.channel.send('Got it!')

        # wait for 10 seconds, then delete message and reply
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await message.delete()
        await reply.delete()
    else:
        # process other commands (if there are none, delete this line)
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

---

Note that this implementation assumes there will be no commands in the requests channel (which from my understanding is what you intended, anyway)